# What does the annotation @template mean in PHP doc blocks?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, faker, docblocks

I could see this PHPDoc block in the [FakerPHP/Faker](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker) package, and I'm not aware what does `@template` mean? you can find it in the package's main branch on this [line](https://github.com/FakerPHP/Faker/blob/main/src/Faker/Generator.php#L574)

```php
/**
 * @template T of Extension\Extension
 *
 * @param class-string<T> $id
 *
 * @throws ContainerExceptionInterface
 * @throws Extension\ExtensionNotFound
 *
 * @return T
 */
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The @template annotation relates to a concept called Generics, which does not currently exist in PHP, but are a way of dynamically describing the contents of a parameter or return type that would be unknown until a class is instantiated or method called.

For PHP specifically, [here is an article describing the doc blocks themselves and how to use them](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs).

For the code you referenced, the template specifies T will be an instance of Extension\Extension.  The $id parameter will be the class name for T, and @return says the method will return an instance of T.

Using the method would be something like $faker->ext(MyExtension::class), which would return an instance of MyExtension.

If you want to follow the rabbit, [here is more on Generic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming).